# TypeError: Data must be a buffer

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, aes, cryptojs

I have an http request in which I want to pass some sensitive data so I tried to encrypted these data.
In my React Native app I generated a pair of keys with react-native-rsa-native and I crypte my string with the public key via the function RSA.encrypt(my string, my public key).

After this I send the generated crypt data in my http request and I try to decrypt it in my node.js environment (Google Cloud Functions). For this I use the Crypto module.

I import it with:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
```

And I try to decrypt my data with the RSA private key generated in my react-native module :

```
crypto.privateDecrypt(rsaPrivateKey, myCryptedString)
```

But I obtain the error:

> TypeError: Data must be a buffer
>       at TypeError (native)
>       at Object.privateDecrypt (crypto.js:375:12)
>       at exports.createPaymentMethod.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:928:10)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:37:41)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:783:7
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:766:11
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback 
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)

Does someone have a solution to my issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_privatedecrypt_privatekey_buffer), the ciphertext should be an instance of `Buffer` rather than a `String`, therefore you can try to wrap the ciphertext into a buffer:

`crypto.privateDecrypt(rsaPrivateKey, Buffer.from(myCryptedString))`

Comment: Thank you it's working, but I now have this error : error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Maybe it is an issue of keys ? I removed all the lines breaks on my two generated keys, is it possibly the cause or it has no influence ?

Comment: @Joris My pleasure. I assume it's quite possible that the new error occurs due to unrecognized key format. However, I am not really sure, sorry.